# Apache HUE, can login using REST API, but the rest doesn't work

Tags: django, csrf, hue

I'm struggling with Apache HUE Rest API and django csrf.

The problem is that I can kind-a login, but the rest doesn't work. I always get redirected to login page. Seems like server doesn't like my `csrftoken` or `sessionid` cookie.

I have absolutely no idea why.
Here is my login code:

```scala
val accessToken = getAccessToken(Http(s"$baseUrl/accounts/login/?next=/").asString)
    val response =
      Http(s"$baseUrl/accounts/login/")
        .postForm(Seq(
          "username" -> username,
          "password" -> password,
          "csrfmiddlewaretoken" -> accessToken.csrftoken.getValue,
          "next" -> "/"
        ))
        .cookie(accessToken.csrftoken)
        .asString
    getAccessToken(response) // wrapper for cookies and headers from response
```

Now I try just to get page from HUE protected with csrf

```scala
 def getDir(hdfsPathDirParent: String): Unit = {
    val accessToken = login()
    val response = Http(s"$baseUrl/filebrowser/view=$hdfsPathDirParent")
      .cookie(accessToken.csrftoken) // retrieved after login
      .cookie(accessToken.sessionid) // retrieved after login
      .header("X-CSRFToken", accessToken.csrftoken.getValue)
      .header("Host", "localhost:8888")
      .header("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9")
      .header("Connection", "keep-alive")
      .header("Sec-Fetch-Dest", "empty")
      .header("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "cors")
      .header("Sec-Fetch-Site", "same-origin")
      //.header("Sec-Fetch-User", "?1")
      .header("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1")
      .header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36")
      .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")

      .header("Accept-Language", "en,en-US;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8")
      .header("Cache-Control", "max-age=0")
      .header("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")

      .asString
```

I literally copy-pasted all tokens from Google Chrome debug panel. It doesn't work

```
[30/May/2020 05:19:29 -0700] access       WARNING  172.17.0.1 test_user - "POST /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1" -- Successful login for user: test_user
[30/May/2020 05:19:29 -0700] middleware   INFO     Redirecting to login page: /filebrowser/view=/user/test_user
[30/May/2020 05:19:29 -0700] access       INFO     172.17.0.1 -anon- - "GET /filebrowser/view=/user/test_user HTTP/1.1" -- login redirection
```

So I do pass login form, but the rest doesn't work. Can't find what I miss...

Their code example doesn't work

```
http://cloudera.github.io/hue/latest/developer/api/
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you getting back a HTTP 302 redirect instead of a 200? (so you would need to follow it with your code).

Also above doc site is stale, https://docs.gethue.com/developer/api/#python is the new one.

Comment: Yes, I do get 302, but the root cause is invalid auth. Browser (I use Chrome dev console) gets 302 too, but Location is http://localhost:8888/filebrowser/view=/user/cloudera
My code gets Location : Vector(http://localhost:8888/accounts/login/?next=/filebrowser/mkdir)
and hue server thinks I'm anonymous and redirects me to login page...

Comment: BTW code from new one link doesn't work too. It can't login
```
[30/May/2020 11:37:19 -0700] decorators   INFO     AXES: Calling decorated function: dt_login
[30/May/2020 11:37:19 -0700] middleware   INFO     Redirecting to login page: /metastore/databases/default/metadata
[30/May/2020 11:37:19 -0700] access       INFO     172.17.0.1 -anon- - "GET /metastore/databases/default/metadata HTTP/1.1" -- login redirection
[30/May/2020 11:37:19 -0700] decorators   INFO     AXES: Calling decorated function: dt_login```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be intuitive
but

```scala
def getDir(accessToken: CookiesAndHeaders, hdfsPathDirParent: String): (String, CookiesAndHeaders) = {
    val req = Http(s"$baseUrl/filebrowser/view=$hdfsPathDirParent")
      .cookie(accessToken.sessionid)
    val response = req.asString
```

just **DO NOT*** pass csrftoken as cookie, use ONLY **sessionid** sessionid Cookie.
I have no idea why, but it helped...